# Excel/Calc: Pivot table with (almost) identical row: how to identify them?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, openoffice, spreadsheet

I need to examine via pivot a datasource from a sheet. This datasource sheet is something like this:

| Field 1 | Field 1 | Field 3 |

| AAAA   | **BBBB**   | CCCC   |

| DDDD  | EEEE   | FFFF   |

| GGGG  | HHHH   | IIII   |

| KKKK  | **BBBB** | LLLL   |

My pivot table is such that Field 1 and Field 2 **must* be used as "row area" (on the left).

The problem is that since I've two different "group by" value for BBBB (i.e., AAAA+BBBB and KKKK+BBBB) I see two null-valued row for Field 1, one for AAAA and one for KKKK.

I understand the logic behind this, but I need a clearer way to identify then the null-value on field 1, such as, AAAA+BBBB and KKKK+BBBB.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the simil-duplicate issue are always auto-kept one under the other, so my pivot table read something like it:

| AAAA | BBBB | CCCC |

| KKKK | null | LLLL |

So the first one kind of works like a "title" for both of them. Clever trick!